# ViewGroup in ContentPage - ExportRenderer issue Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I want to have an Android.Widget.RelativeLayout added in a ContentPage. For this I've followed multiple online examples:

[Xamarin Forms Custom Renderer for Android not displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33159798/xamarin-forms-custom-renderer-for-android-not-displaying)

[Adding an "Android.Views.ViewGroup" to a Xamarin XAML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48447283/adding-an-android-views-viewgroup-to-a-xamarin-xaml-page)

and others.

But I cannot get it working.

In my shared project I have:

```
namespace SharedProject
{
  public partial class App : Application
    {

        public App ()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
        }
     ....
    }
```

space

```
namespace SharedProject
{
    public class MyCustomViewControl : View
    {
        public MyCustomViewControl()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

and the MainPage.xaml which is being rendered:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:SharedProject="clr-namespace:SharedProject;assembly=SharedProject"
             x:Class="SharedProject.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <SharedProject:MyCustomViewControl
                                 HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

and in the MonoAndroid project:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyCustomViewControl), typeof(MyCustomViewRenderer))]
namespace SharedProject.Mobile.Droid
{
    public class MyCustomViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<MyCustomViewControl, RelativeLayout>
    {
        public MyCustomViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {

        }

        private Android.Widget.RelativeLayout rlMainContainer;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<MyCustomViewControl> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement != null || Element == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            rlMainContainer = new RelativeLayout(Context);
            rlMainContainer.SetMinimumHeight(50);
            rlMainContainer.SetMinimumWidth(100);
            rlMainContainer.LayoutParameters = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent);

            if (Control == null)
                SetNativeControl(rlMainContainer);

            MainActivity.instance.setActiveReader(Control);
        }
    }
}
```

And in my MainActivity.OnCreate I have:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);


            instance = this;

            LoadApplication(new App());
```

I was expecting that when the MainPage is being rendered, the rlMainContainer would be also added to it as per the MainPage.xaml and OnElementChanged, but nothing inside MyCustomViewRenderer is being requested(no breakpoint hits).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of file comparison(my project and the Microsoft sample one), I found the issue to be related to the

`MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());`.

To solve it I just removed `NavigationPage` wrapper.

`MainPage = new MainPage();`.

Do not know yet why this happened, but if anyone knows please edit my answer with an explanation as well.

Edit: The Renderer works with `NavigationPage` as well, but only after the OnCreate method finishes executing.

Comment: Odd, I used the navigation page in my test, and that worked. Must be something else going on not shown in the code you posted.

Comment: @jgoldberger yes, I just played around with the CustomRenderer from Microsoft and it appears that if you use the `NavigationPage` wrapper, the renderer will work, but only after the onCreate method finished executing.

Answer (score 1):

I just plugged your code into a new project and it worked fine as long as I was explicit about which RelativeLayout I wanted to use. There are 2 possible, Xamarin.Forms.RelativeLayout and Android.Widget.Relative layout. I assume you want the latter, but I don't see it being fully qualified, and since I assume you have using statements for both Xamarin.Forms (needed for the ExportRenderer attribute) and Android.Widget (needed for the RelativeLayout) it is not clear that you are using the correct RelativeLayout in all places.

There is also the question of whether you are using the `Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.ViewRenderer` or the `Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ViewRenderer`. Most use AppCompat as the default Xam.Forms template uses the `FormsAppCompatActivity`. So assuming you are using AppCompat, the following full source code (with full type qualifications as necessary) for the custom renderer is working on my end:

```
using System;
using Android.Content;
using TestRelLayout;
using TestRelLayout.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyCustomViewControl), typeof(MyCustomViewRenderer))]
namespace TestRelLayout.Droid
{
    public class MyCustomViewRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.ViewRenderer<MyCustomViewControl, Android.Widget.RelativeLayout>
    {
        public MyCustomViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        private Android.Widget.RelativeLayout rlMainContainer;


        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<MyCustomViewControl> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement != null || Element == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            rlMainContainer = new Android.Widget.RelativeLayout(Context);
            rlMainContainer.SetMinimumHeight(50);
            rlMainContainer.SetMinimumWidth(100);
            rlMainContainer.LayoutParameters = new Android.Widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(Android.Widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, Android.Widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent);
            // set the background color to make it easy to see if renderer is working               
            rlMainContainer.SetBackgroundColor(
                        Android.Graphics.Color.Aquamarine);

            if (Control == null)
                SetNativeControl(rlMainContainer);

            // did not bother to set this up in my MainActivity
            //MainActivity.instance.setActiveReader(Control);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for such a comprehensive answer. Regarding the `RelativeLayout` part I had a using statement like `using RelativeLayout = Android.Widget.RelativeLayout;` which should be fine, but I am using the `Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ViewRenderer`. I will give the other one a try, but they mention nothing about the AppCombat on their website https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/view or the other answers. From now on I'll also post the using statement in my questions.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to render a native Android RelativeLayout? There are build in options in Xamarin.Forms. Look at this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/controls/layouts#relativelayout)

Comment: This is not an answer, it would've been better to add it as a comment. I actually need a ViewGroup element(RelativeLayout in my case) because I want to use it as a parameter in another function.

Comment: Ok, if you are working in Forms why do you expect a RelativeLayout as a parameter in a function?

Comment: Because I'm using an external library which expects it.